# How to extract all compressed Z files in a directory?

Tags: fedora

I am on Fedora 35 and I have a directory full of `.Z` I have to extract within the directory. Here is an example of how they are named:

```
GIRAF.2021-02-14T00:59:35.569.fits.Z
```

I was wondering if there was a command I could type in the terminal that extracts all `.Z` files in the directory?

Comment: I would first try `gunzip -vt *.Z` to see if there are any problems.  If none, then `gunzip *.Z`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is given by [rickhg12hs.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1409374/rickhg12hs)

First, try `gunzip -vt *.Z` to see if there are any problems.

If none, then `gunzip *.Z`